# Do there exist Touchstone/S2P/SnP files for capacitors and inductors in the public domain?

Tags: rf, filter, impedance-matching, data

I'm writing a [Touchstone Perl module](https://metacpan.org/release/EWHEELER/PDL-IO-Touchstone-1.001/view/lib/PDL/IO/Touchstone.pm) for reading and transforming Touchstone files to different parameter (S, Y, Z, etc) and format (DB, MA, RI) types.  ([Touchstone](https://ibis.org/connector/touchstone_spec11.pdf) is also known as .s2p files or [s-parameter files](https://www.murata.com/en-us/tool/data/sparameterdata).)

I would like to package the library with `.s2p` files to test routines and make sure they are working correctly on different platforms, however, s2p data from manufacturers is intellectual property and I want to be careful about repackaging their (possibly) proprietary data.

**Questions:**

- Are there s2p (or >2 port) touchstone files in the public domain that I can package without stepping on the click-through EULA of different manufacturers?
- Do you know any manufacturers who release their RF data files under a generous creative-commons or other copyleft type of license?  The original data file source will (of course!) receive attribution.

Ultimately I would like a few L, R, C samples, maybe a few filters or amplifiers as well.

Comment: I'm wholly unfamiliar with what a touchstone file is, but could you make your own, one that represents a theoretical device rather than a real one?

Comment: @Hearth, possibly.  I might be able to generate ideal component files, and I've considered that.  The nice thing about those provided by mfg's is that they are noisy real-life and more "interesting" for evaluating a test.  Locked in a padded room everything works fine, but in the wild who knows.  (fyi, touchstone is also known as .s2p files or s-parameter files. eg: https://www.murata.com/en-us/tool/data/sparameterdata)

Comment: Have you contacted any manufacturers to see if they can give you some to use? Particularly some of the smaller ones might be happy that it would get their name out there. Even if the license is normally too restrictive, you might be able to get them to relicense a few select ones. Though it's a bit of a long shot.

Comment: Can't you just *measure* some part in a VNA and generate the Touchstone file?

Comment: @Hearth thats what I was thinking next actually.  THanks.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, sure, but my NanoVNA isnt currently plumbed for such a job!  But thats also a good idea.  A really good idea, maybe a fun project to setup too.

Comment: Are you going to redistribute these files to others? Or just use them for your own study/analysis/testing your test routine/etc?

Comment: @ThePhoton, redistribute as part of the module test suite here: https://metacpan.org/release/EWHEELER/PDL-IO-Touchstone-1.001/view/lib/PDL/IO/Touchstone.pm